# Container Packing in YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, qubole

Qubole has implemented [Container Packing in YARN](https://www.qubole.com/blog/container-packing-a-new-algorithm-for-resource-scheduling-in-the-cloud/) for cloud deployments to reduce infrastructure cost, is there any similar implementation available in open source world?

Comment: *Qubole uses FairScheduler in YARN to schedule containers, and Container Packing is implemented via the FairScheduler. The following configuration options are relevant to using Container Packing in Qubole... (list of all configurations)*... Have you tried playing with those settings in open source YARN?

Comment: @cricket_007 these configs don't exist in open source YARN